# How do you make golden syrup?

Tags: sugar, syrup

I want to make some [anzac biscuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anzac_biscuits) which calls for golden syrup, but don't really want to buy a jar (what's the fun in that?).

What are some good recipes?  A google search shows a wide variety - from using corn syrup to adding lemon/lime slices.

Comment: AFAIK, golden syrup is a byproduct of the sugar cane refinement process ... are you asking for substitutes?

Comment: I'm asking how to make it at home, or at least a close approximation.

Answer (score 4):

In Britain golden syrup is used in a lot of things, Lyle's brand is the one people know, though there are a few other minor brands. They tend to vary in thickness and strength of taste, but usually have fairly similar tastes. It is partially inverted sugar syrup, which has a fairly complicated chemical process to manufacture from byproducts of the refining industry. I doubt it's very easy at all to make at home.

Buy a whole tin, it is quite versatile, excellent in cakes and best of all on porridge.

Quick tip: If you need to add a large amount to a recipe which asks you to heat it, which is quite common, it is far easier to place the tin (with the lid off!) in the oven for a few minutes and carefully wearing gloves pour from the tin, as the heat makes it thinner and thus pourable.  Same thing works for black treacle.

Comment: +1 _2.  Chiefly British Molasses._ Always trying to learn that words!

Comment: [here's great information](http://www.azeliaskitchen.net/blog/liquid-glucose-the-answer-to-perfect-ice-cream-and-more/) about inverted sugar and the why for adding glucose

Comment: @zanlok Excellent link, good information.

Answer (score 3):

ANZAC biscuits are a historically significant type of biscuit. If you change the recipe they wont be ANZAC biscuits. They will probably taste nice, but just wont be ANZAC biscuits. I guess it's like having duck for Thanksgiving?

Golden syrup is a key to the taste and cooking functions of ANZAC's. You need a sugar that under heat does not entirely let go. I guess you could try a mix of corn syrup and melted natural brown sugar (Muscovado sugar) to get the strength, flavour, and colour

There is not much you can change in the ANZAC recipe without ending up with a very different product. Even substituting oil for butter is a disaster

Golden syrup if really nice in many recipes, or just smeared on toast in the morning for a pick-me-up. So a tin in the cupboard is always handy

[The official NZ recipe](http://www.anzac.govt.nz/significance/traditions.html), but use 2 tablespoons of Golden syrup, every one I know does, and I doubt they had half tablespoons in 1915 :-)

Comment: Do all brands of golden syrup taste the same?

Comment: +1 Yep, in fact for naming something _Anzak_ in Australia you must guarantee to follow the traditional recipe, or change the name, which is protected by federal legislation. http://www.adelaidenow.com.au/news/south-australia/fast-food-giant-cuts-anzac-biscuit/story-e6frea83-1111117545075

Comment: @Trey-Jackson More or less yes, the few I have tried where much the same. It is meant to be a byproduct of refined sugar cane. Some are made from other products like corn or beets, so they probably taste somewhat different